# PHP preg_replace ampersand

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Okay I might not be going about this the right way, but here goes..

I have this string that takes a link and extracts the text between the  tags...

```
$string = $item;
$pattern = '/\<a([^>]*)\>([^<]*)\<\/a\>/i';
$replacement = '$2';
$message = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

There are a few items in this string that have ampersands (in the text portion, not the tag portion), however most don't. I'm trying to figure out a way to either incorporate the ampersand into the current pattern or do another preg_replace on the `$message` to remove the ampersand after the tags are striped away.

THANKS!

Comment: If you're thinking about multiple regex's, you're either overcomplicating things, or you're a slave of [Cthulu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)... really: save yourself a lot of trouble and _PARSE_ the html. As you said yourself: you're not going about it the right way, so mend your ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to remove everything after the ampersand? Then it's

```
'/\<a([^>]*)\>([^<&]*)[^<]*\<\/a\>/i';
```

Otherwise, you'll need a 2nd operation.

BTW: Your regex will also match other tags starting with `<a`, such as the `<author>` or the `<audio>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! The <a issue isn't a big deal because I'm replacing an array that solely contains links, but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 7):

There's always `$message = str_replace('&', '', $message);`

Incidentally, if you are trying to strip tags from html input, there is also `strip_tags`

for example, if your input is

```
$text = '<a href="google.com">Text</a>';
```

Then `strip_tags($text)` will produce `Text`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which worked! I chose the other answer since it was a little bit cleaner. But I'll keep `strip_tags($text)` in mind for next time! THANKS!